# mysqli update function not updating row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I m trying to update an item, and I don't know why `$q->affected_rows` is returning '0.

Some data, which seems right when checked:

`var_dump($query_parts)` - `string(40) "item_description = ?, item_publisher = ?"`

`var_dump($prep)` - `string(3) "sii"`

`var_dump($values)`

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  &string(12) "Description"
  [1]=>
  &string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  &string(3) "729"
}
```

`var_dump($q)` - `bool(true)`

```
public function editItem($editInfo)
{
    $userItemIDS = array();

    $query_parts = '';
    $prep = '';

    //move item_id to end of $editInfo array
    $item_id = $editInfo['item_id'];

    unset($editInfo['item_id']);

    $editInfo['item_id'] = $item_id;

    $editFiltered = array_filter($editInfo);

    $theData = $this->helperClass->data($editFiltered);
    $columns = $theData[0];
    $values = $theData[1];

    (!empty($editInfo['item_description']) ? $prep .= "s" : "");
    (!empty($editInfo['item_publisher']) ? $prep .= "i" : "");
    (!empty($editInfo['item_year']) ? $prep .= "i" : "");
    (!empty($editInfo['item_number']) ? $prep .= "i" : "");
    (!empty($item_id) ? $prep .= "i" : "");

    unset($editInfo['item_id']);

    foreach($editInfo as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(!empty($editInfo[$key]))
        {
            $query_parts .= "".$key." = ?, ";
        }
    }

    $query_parts = substr($query_parts, 0, -2);

    var_dump($query_parts);

    $q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("UPDATE items SET ".$query_parts." WHERE id = ?");

    $userItemIDS = $this->helperClass->userItemIDS();
    //var_dump($userItemIDS);
    if( !in_array($item_id, $userItemIDS) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    if($q)
    {

        //var_dump($q);
        var_dump($prep);
        var_dump($values);

        call_user_func_array( array($q, 'bind_param'), array_merge(array($prep), $values) );

        $q->execute();
        $a_r = $q->affected_rows;
        $q->close();

        return $a_r;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have 3 placeholders (`item_description`, `item_publisher`, `id`) in your prepared query but `array_merge(array($prep), $values)` will result in an array with 4 entries. I also don't know why `$prep` should have the value `sii` - you never assign a value to `$prep` in the above script.

Comment: Hi. `$prep` get assigned values here `(!empty($editInfo['item_description']) ? $prep .= "s" : "");` and var_dump($values) returns only 3 items.

Comment: I'm sorry - I haven't seen it. Have you checked my first comment regarding the matching of placeholders and binded values in your prepared statement?

Comment: Hmm ... you re right. It also includes $prep giving it an extra entry.

Comment: But shouldn't that give an error ?